# Elements of a sigma-algebra countable sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\mathcal{C}$ is the collection of all singleton subsets of $\mathbf{R}$.
How do I show that every element of the sigma-algebra generated by $\mathcal{C}$ is either a countable set or the complement of a countable set?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\cal B$ be the collection of all subsets of $\mathbb R$ that are either countable or co-countable.  Show that this is a $\sigma$-algebra, and that it contains $\cal C$.

Comment: How do I show this? I'm really quite lost here :/

Comment: @PrincessAmazia What part of the definition of $\sigma$-algebra are you having trouble verifying for $\mathcal{B}$?

Comment: Everything, I'm not a set theorist nor a mathematician. I'm just trying to understand the basics.

Comment: OK, I'll get you started.  The first requirement for a $\sigma$-algebra (as listed by Wikipedia) is that it is nonempty.  Is there at least one subset of $\mathbb R$ that is either countable or co-countable?

Comment: I guess any point would do as a subset? So yes, for example {0}.

Comment: Yes, that works. Second, a $\sigma$-algebra is closed under complementation, i.e. if a set $A$ is in it, then $A^c$ is also in it. Is this true for the collection of sets in question?